# Primefaces - Tamanho columnToggler

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Eu tenho uma datatable com uma columnToggler, porem gostaria de retirar os campos sem aumentar o tamanho do primeiro campo. Estou Usando o Primefaces 6.0.

```
<p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{dtBasicView.cars}">
    <f:facet name="header">
        List of Cars

        <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns" style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
        <p:columnToggler datasource="cars" trigger="toggler" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Id">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Year">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Brand">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.brand}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Color">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Price">
        <h:outputText value="#{car.price}">
            <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, pode ser mais claro por favor?

Comment: @Douglas eu seleciono o toggler e vou retirando as colunas da datatable. gostaria de não retirar a primeira coluna, porem quando remover as outras colunas gostaria que a primeira coluna não modificasse a largura original.

Comment: Já tentou definir tamanhos fixos para as colunas usando <p:column width=150px> por exemplo ?

Comment: @hebertrfreitas já fiz sim, porem não da certo. quando tiro uma coluna com o toggler ela aumenta o tamanho das outras.